# How do I create a shortcut and place on the desktop?

Tags: command-line, scripts, executable

I would like to create a shortcut which will cd to a particular directory and then execute a .sh file, thereby opening my application.

At the moment I enter the following into the terminal:

```
cd /opt/intel/vtune_amplifier_xe_2013
```

then

```
source amplxe-vars.sh
```

and

```
amplxe-gui
```

so I create an executable file on the desktop which has:

```
source /opt/intel/vtune_amplifier_xe_2013/amplxe-vars.sh
amplxe-gui
```

and set it's properties to be executable. However, when I double click and choose run or run in terminal, it doesnt open the application. However the exact same commands work in terminal?

Answer (score 4):

To create a shortcut on your desktop follow these steps:

1. Create a file with a name of your choice and with the extension `.desktop`

   e. g. `minecraft.desktop`
2. Open the file with your text editor (File > Open... or Drag and Drop)
3. Inside the file type the following:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]

   Encoding=UTF-8

   Name={Name Of The Application Of Anything Else}

   Comment={Optional}

   Exec=/bin/sh "{directory of the script e. g. /home/zignd/script.sh}"

   Icon={directory of the icon (Optional) e. g. /home/zignd/Pictures/Icon.png}

   Categories={(Optional) e.g. Games,Media,Development}

   Type=Application

   Terminal=0
   ```

   Note that you need to delete the the brackets and what is inside it. You can also use this shortcut in the launcher just drag and drop it.
4. Save it and enjoy your shortcut.